# Python Prime_Numbers Algorihtms TypeError()

Tags: python

TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.

If I use Integer It will not include 3 as Prime Number...I do not want to add 3 same like 1...

Code-->

```
import  math
def is_prime(n):

    if n==1:
        return False

    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n > 2  and  n%2 == 0:
        return  False

    max_divisor =math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
    for d  in range(3,1 + max_divisor , 2 ) :
        if  n  %  d  == 0  :
            return False
        return  True



for n in range(1,21):
    print (n,is_prime(n))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of using `math.floor()`, just cast the square root to an `int`, i.e: `max_divisor = int(math.sqrt(n))`
2. The `return True` should be outside of the for loop
3. You might also want to add something to catch weird input, such as `if type(n) is not int or n <= 0` -> `return None`. If you have this you can also eliminate the first part of `if n > 2  and  n%2 == 0:`

The following should work:

```
import math
def is_prime(n):
    if type(n) is not int or n <= 0:
        return None

    if n==1:
        return False

    if n == 2:
        return True

    if n%2 == 0:
        return  False

    max_divisor = int(math.sqrt(n))
    for d in range(3, 1 + max_divisor, 2):
        if n % d == 0  :
            return False
    return True

for n in range(1,21):
    print (n,is_prime(n))
```

Output:

```
$ python review.py
(1, False)
(2, True)
(3, True)
(4, False)
(5, True)
(6, False)
(7, True)
(8, False)
(9, False)
(10, False)
(11, True)
(12, False)
(13, True)
(14, False)
(15, False)
(16, False)
(17, True)
(18, False)
(19, True)
(20, False)
```

If the range at the end is just to demonstrate that your function works then that's fine. But if you specifically need the primes over an interval, try implementing a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) instead.